# Erro ao criar função mysql

Tags: mysql, funções

Estou tentando criar a seguinte função:

```
DELIMITER //
FUNCTION DISTANCIA ( lat1 DOUBLE, long1 DOUBLE,  lat2 DOUBLE,  long2 DOUBLE )   RETURNS DOUBLE
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE d2r DOUBLE;
    DECLARE dlong DOUBLE;
    DECLARE dlat DOUBLE;
    DECLARE temp_sin DOUBLE;
    DECLARE temp_cos DOUBLE;
    DECLARE temp_cos2 DOUBLE;
    DECLARE temp_sin2 DOUBLE;
    DECLARE a DOUBLE;
    DECLARE c DOUBLE;

    set d2r = 0.017453292519943295769236;

    set dlong = (long2 - long1) * d2r;
    set dlat = (lat2 - lat1) * d2r;

    set temp_sin = sin(dlat/2.0);
    set temp_cos = cos(lat1 * d2r);
    set temp_cos2 = cos(lat2 * d2r);
    set temp_sin2 = sin(dlong/2.0);

    set a = (temp_sin * temp_sin2) + (temp_cos * temp_cos2) * (temp_sin2);
    set c = 2.0 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1.0 - a));

    return 6368.1 * c;
END //
```

E esta me retornano o seguinte erro, o que poderia ser ?

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near 'FUNCTION DISTANCIA ( lat1 DOUBLE, long1 DOUBLE, lat2 DOUBLE,
>   long2 DOUBLE ) ' at line 1

A primeira linha ai é:

```
FUNCTION DISTANCIA ( lat1 DOUBLE, long1 DOUBLE,  lat2 DOUBLE,  long2 DOUBLE )   RETURNS DOUBLE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faltou um `CREATE` antes de `FUNCTION`

```
...
CREATE FUNCTION DISTANCIA ( lat1 DOUBLE, long1 DOUBLE,  lat2 DOUBLE,  long2 DOUBLE )   RETURNS DOUBLE
...
```

Comment: putis, verdade , vlw.